# How to ensure a user has a valid Paypal account to accept payments with?

Tags: php, paypal, payment, verification, account

I ask my users to provide a Paypal account on which they will receive automatic payments (through Paypal PHP SDK) and I want to be sure such account is valid ( active and ready to accept payments) **before** the first payment occurs (e.g. when they sign-up. Of course I'm aware the account status may change in the meanwhile). Does Paypal provide a better way (or is there a smarter flow) to achieve this  without a classic 0.01$ transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of our classic API called `GetVerifiedStatus`.

This API basically check against the status of PayPal Account, whether it is Verified or Unverified. You can even get whether the account is a Business account or Personal Account. There are a lot of other information which you could get.

Do visit the specific [API's page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) for more information on the response values you would get upon calling this API.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I came across this API later. Do I need any special permission to use it? Also, given that using it I can check wether an account is verified or not, is "verified account" equivalent to "an account that can accept payments"? (i.e. is it the same thing, or is it a superset or a subset?)

Comment: I am pretty sure, as long as it is Premier/Business account, it can start accepting payment. You can test all the theory on an sandbox environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try implement with  Paypal Rest Api https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/;
where you can validate your paypal account easily.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to implement "Login with Paypal" using Paypal OAuth APIs so that you can directly get the Paypal account, account status, account type, country etc.

Checkout [Verifying Paypal IDs by Implementing Login with Paypal](http://usefulangle.com/post/66/php-verify-paypal-account) for a detailed tutorial.